# Threading the same object process with a list of many objects

Tags: java, multithreading, optimization

**My question is:** What's the "best" way to control threading a list of many "`RunnableObject`s"?

I have a way that I approach multithreading, but I don't think it's optimal. There are many instances where I have a list of objects which all need to do the same thing, but I don't want them to do them one at a time, so I'll put them in a list and thread some of them at once. When one is finished, it calls an `updateList()` method on the controller which will remove the finished items and call new ones. I don't think this is a very good way to go about it. I'd like to use something like `.notify()`, but I'm not sure how it works in this context (directing me to a good site to learn may be useful).

I have a basic outline of my controller class below. **I've tried to make the javadoc useful**, so if you're into skimming, go ahead and just read that. Thanks.

**Just some sample code** to give you the idea of what I'm talking about.

```
package controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import model.RunnableObject;

public class RunnableObjectController {

  private static RunnableObjectController instance;
  private List<RunnableObject> runnableObjects = new ArrayList<>();
  private List<RunnableObject> queuedRunnableObjects = new ArrayList<>();
  private List<RunnableObject> currentRunnableObjects = new ArrayList<>();
  private int limit = 10;

  private RunnableObjectController() {
  }

  public static RunnableObjectController getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
      instance = new RunnableObjectController();
    }
    return instance;
  }

  /**
  * Updates the list.
  */
  public void begin() {
    updateList();
  }

  /**
   * Called by a runnableObject when it's finished with its process
   */
  public synchronized void updateList() {
    removeFinishedRunnableObjects();
    addNewRunnableObjects();
    if (isFinished()) {
      MainController.getInstance().finish();
    }
  }

  /**
  * Searches the currentRunnableObjects for runnableObjects which are not in progress and removes them from the currentRunnableObjects.
  * It will add them to the queuedRunnableObjects if they are of status WAITING.
  */
  private void removeFinishedRunnableObjects() {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < currentRunnableObjects.size()) {
      RunnableObject runnableObject = currentRunnableObjects.get(i);
      if (runnableObject.getStatus() != RunnableObject.IN_PROGRESS) {
        currentRunnableObjects.remove(runnableObject);
        if (runnableObject.getStatus() == RunnableObject.WAITING) {
          queuedRunnableObjects.add(runnableObject);
        }
      } else {
        i++;
      }
    }
  }

  /**
  * Searches the queuedRunnableObjects and adds them to the currentRunnableObjects while the size of the currentRunnableObjects is less than the limit.
  * Begins the runnableObject in a new thread and sets its status to IN_PROGRESS
  */
  private void addNewRunnableObjects() {
    while (!queuedRunnableObjects.isEmpty() && currentRunnableObjects.size() < limit) {
      RunnableObject runnableObject = queuedRunnableObjects.get(0);
      if (runnableObject.getStatus() == RunnableObject.WAITING) {
        addCurrentRemoveQueued(runnableObject);
        new Thread(runnableObject).start();
        runnableObject.setStatus(RunnableObject.IN_PROGRESS);
      }
    }
  }

  /**
  * Adds the runnableObject to the currentThreadsObjects and removes it from the queuedRunnableObjects
  */
  private synchronized void addCurrentRemoveQueued(RunnableObject runnableObject) {
    currentRunnableObjects.add(runnableObject);
    queuedRunnableObjects.remove(runnableObject);
  }

  /**
   * Checks whether the current and queued notification lists are empty. Returns true if they both are.
   *
   * @return
   */
  private boolean isFinished() {
    if (queuedRunnableObjects.isEmpty() && currentRunnableObjects.isEmpty()) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you reinventing the wheel? Is this homework or just for personal education?  Can you not use the classes in `java.util.concurrent`?

Comment: Not homework :) Personal education. I find myself needing to do something like this all the time.

Comment: If you haven't studied `java.util.concurrent` I strongly suggest you do so.  If you have, it would help for you to update your post explaining why that framework doesn't do what you want.

Comment: I haven't studied `java.util.concurrent`, thanks for the tip, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have just reinvented the [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)!

Since you are using java 7, it would be tempting to use the new fork join API, but I am pretty sure that in your case the ThreadPoolExecutor is what you need.

Comment: In your case, the equivalent is Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10); which will create 10 threads to execute yours